# Density of states, $\pi$ vs $2\pi$

Tags: condensed-matter, density-of-states

When calculating density of states for an electron, some arrive that k (the wavenumber) is $2\pi n x /L $ and some say it is $\pi n x /L$?

Where L is the dimension of the well

I’ve heard vague explanations of “you’re using only one quadrant of k space” but I truly have no idea what they’re talking about.

What is the difference in these two results and why does it occur?

Comment: This might be easier to answer with the context of what is in the (parentheses).

Comment: Hopefully it’s clearer now

Comment: Basically this difference is because of boundary condition. Pi case is for zero boundary (and this you’re considering standing wave, so k can only be positive) and 2pi for periodic boundary condition (where k can be negative).